# React Kepler Mapbox API key

Tags: react-native, mapbox, deck.gl, kepler.gl

I am new to React and have used an example to put together a map to show data using Kepler. I am using a default token in my .env.local file. I created that file under my project folder using new file and giving it a name and then I only have the following line in it.

```
REACT_APP_MAPBOX_API = pk.someletters.hello
```

// Keep in mind this token is the default token that I got when I created my account with mapbox. Is it ok to use the default token?

The way I am using it in my app.js iss

```
  <KeplerGl
    id="Test"

    mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_API}
    width={window.innerWidth}
    height={window.innerHeight}
    />
```

The page renders but with this error. 
Its clearly not getting the  mapbox identifier from the .env.local file.

```
index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `mapboxApiAccessToken` is marked as required in `MapContainer`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

What am I not doing correctly here?

Also there is a warning coming that says

```
kepler-gl.js:179 Mapbox Token not valid. [Click here](https://github.com/keplergl/kepler.gl#mapboxapiaccesstoken-string-required)
```

When I click on that it just takes me back creating an account with mapbox and accessing token.  Do I need to make a token with any consideration? or default is good.

Anyone?

Comment: Are you using a package like dotenv to loads environment variables from a .env file into process.env?